# Accessing files in EC2 from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

I have few EC2 servers in AWS. Whenever the disk space exceeds a limit, i want to delete some files (may be logs folder) in EC2 instance automatically. I am planning to use Lambda and cloudwatch for this. Can i use Lambda to interact with EC2. If not possible, what is the alternate approach to achieve this functionality.

Comment: How do you plan to delete the files? using scripts?

Comment: Is it a windows server EC2 or a linux one?

Comment: Yes planning to delete using scripts. It is windows EC2 server.

Comment: The intention to cleanup the disk. Is scripts the best way to do? Else suggest the most recommended way.

Comment: why don't you just use windows scheduler and local bat/cmd file?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an appropriate use-case for an AWS Lambda function.

AWS Lambda is suitable for tasks where compute is required in response to an event. Your use-case, however, is to manipulate information on an EC2 instance, which does not need cloud compute.

You could run a script on each each computer, triggered by a Scheduled Task.

Alternatively, you could use the [Systems Manager Run Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/run-command.html) (also known as the **EC2 Run Command**), which allows you to run commands on multiple Amazon EC2 instances and view the results. This could be used to trigger a local script, or it could pass the whole command to run (including the script). It is purpose-built for the type of task you describe.

Comment: Thanks John for the suggestion. Is it possible to automate the system manager run command execution without logging into aws console.

Comment: Yes, the Run Command can be triggered via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or an API call. Also, Amazon CloudWatch Events can directly trigger the Run Command, and this can be done on a regular schedule.  See: [Configuring CloudWatch Events for Run Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/rc-cwe.html)

Comment: Let me try it. Thanks John.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda has access to your instances if they are available in the internet. If they are not available in the internet, it is possible to give access to AWS lambda using a NAT or instance Gateway in your VPC.

The problem is: access to your instance does not means access to the instances filesystems. To delete the files from Lambda you can use two alternatives:

1. Configure a network filesystem service in your instances an connect
   to this services in your lambda function. Using windows you would
   just "share" your disks, but in that case you would use some SMB
   library in your lambda code, that "I think" did not have native SMB
   support. Just keep in mind that your security guy will scream out
   loud when you propose this alternative.
2. Create a "agent" in your EC2 instances and keep it running as a
   Windows Service and call this agent from your lambda function. In
   that case, the lambda will start the execution of the agent that
   will be responsible for the file deletion.

Another option, is to follow Ramesh's suggestion and create a Powershell script and configure a cron job. To be easy, you can create a Image with this Powershell script and use the image to initialize each instance. The same solution would be applicable to "the agent" solution in the lambda alternantives.

I think that, in any case, you will need to change something in your 150 servers. Using a customized image can help you to simplify this a little bit, but you will not get a solution without some changes.

Comment: is it possible to call a service which is running in EC2 from Lambda?

Comment: yes, it is. Lambda runs in a container managed by AWS. If you configure your lambda to use your VPC the container will receive a IP address of your VPC. If you didn't change the VPC configuration, lambda will have access to the internet. In each case, you can run a single http client inside your lambda code to make the connnection and reach your EC2 instance. Actually, it don't need to be a http client. You can use any TCP client, but http is simple because of security. Of course you must deliver some service in your EC2 that accepts connections.

Answer (score -1):

According to the following thread, you cannot access files inside a EC2 VM unless you are exposing files to the public using different methodology.

[AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225195)

Quoting from the forum

> If you are talking about the underlying EC2 instance, answer is No, you cannot access those files.

However as a solution for your problem, you can used scheduled job to cleanup your files depending your usage. You can use a service or cron job.

Comment: I have around 150 servers and i want a solution which can be manageable for a long run. Running a job is a overhead where i want to install a service whenever a new instance is created and more effort is needed frequently to validate whether the job is running or not.

Comment: The AWS Forum thread and your response talks about access the undelying EC2 instance filesystem, or: the filesystem of the EC2 instance/container running lambda. Kamal's need to access EC2 instance filesystem in his own VPC.

Comment: @GustavoTavares if you look carefully, answer talks about both scenarios actually. Since it talks about both scenarios, hope you can undo the down vote :)

Comment: @RumeshEranga, I don't see how the question is related to remove files on underlying EC2 instances. Actually, It does not even mention that Lambda is executed in EC2 instances. As per the question, It is very clear that the EC2 instances are related to existent servers, not related to Lambda. The AWS From thread is specifically to discuss this question.

Comment: Sure, I can undo de downvote, but please, try to explain me how you related the question with underling instances.